# cakePHP v2.x - displaying content out of database field

Tags: cakephp

Beginners question: Why is cakePHP not displaying the carriage return/new line and other characters when using;

```
<?php echo h($property['Property']['fullDesc']); ?>
```

I tried using

```
<?php echo $property['Property']['fullDesc']; ?>
```

but both showing output of text as one block of text instead of paragraphs.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The h function is just a wrapper for the php htmlspecialchars() function. It will not convert carriage returns into `<br />` tags. You will need to do something like this:

```
echo nl2br(h($property['Property']['fullDesc']));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it sounds indeed simple new line to br.
Is this somewhere documented? I am using latest version of cakePHP and have read their on-line manual several times.

Comment: Here is the documentation on the h() function and other global function: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

basic PHP...

```
<?php echo nl2br(h($property['Property']['fullDesc'])); ?>
```

nl2br() will form those newlines into `<br>`

Tip: you can make your bake templates include that automatically for all your textarea fields.
See http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/04/24/cake-bake-custom-templates-deluxe/